# IE11 unable to connect to local IIS, other browsers work fine

Tags: internet-explorer, iis

I'm using the XIP.IO wildcard domain to access a website running on a local IIS server.

Today, IE 11 stopped accessing the site, whilst Chrome and Firefox continued to have access. It even works on remote machines, so I know it's related to my local IE.

I've checked there are no proxy settings, reset IIS, reset IE 11, event reinstalled IE 11 - all to no avail. I'm running on Windows 8.1 preview.

This has worked for months without issue. I can't even think of any software that I recently installed that would cause this issue.

As a point of interest, when I fire up Fiddler, IE reports that the "Proxy isn't responding". It's almost as if it can't resolve local IP addresses or something.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Internet Explorer 11 includes a new isolation technology called AppContainer which is used by the Enhanced Protected Mode feature of the browser. EPM/AppContainer network restrictions help mitigate attacks against the computer by preventing content in the Internet Zone from connecting to your local network or your local PC.

The problem you're encountering occurs when the zone settings are such that your Local PC's content is treated as **Internet Zone**. If you were to use the machine name (e.g. `http://mypc` or `http://localhost`) the content would load in the **Intranet Zone** and thus outside of Protected Mode and thus outside of the AppContainer.

The same feature prevents IE11 from using Fiddler in your scenario; you can learn more about this issue here:
http://fiddler2.com/blog/blog/2013/08/02/fiddler-and-internet-explorer-11-on-windows-8-1

To resolve this issue, use the **Win8 Config** tool at the left of Fiddler's toolbar (or download the standalone EnableLoopback tool from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/12/10/fiddler-windows-8-apps-enable-loopback-network-isolation-exemption.aspx)

Comment: I put my xip.io address into the trusted sites list in IE's security settings and that seems to have solved the problem. That's for the explanation.

Comment: Yes, by default, both `Trusted` and `Intranet` run outside of Protected Mode and thus don't run in AppContainer. If you do use Zone Configuration to resolve the problem, take care when testing, as these Zones offer more privileges and if your code were to use them, it would fail when accessed by an end-user who loads it in the `Internet Zone`.

Comment: @EricLaw: Is there a way to permits a 32 bits IE toolbar to work out of  Extended Protected Mode under Win 8.1 RTM 64 bits? Some kind of Trusted zone.

Comment: No. For user-experience reasons (they don't want toolbars to appear and disappear when navigating a tab between zones) you MUST provide both 32bit and 64bit versions of the toolbar to be considered EPM-compatible.

Comment: I had a similar problem but when accessing an Intranet server, not localhost. It wasn't being recognised as Intranet Zone because I didn't have Internet Options > Security > Local Intranet > Sites > 'Automatically detect intranet network' selected. Choosing that means domains without '.' in them are treated as Intranet Zone, and by default therefore not loaded in AppContainer.

Comment: @Rory -- yes, Localhost is blocked for different reasons than Intranet hosts (loopback blocking vs. privateNetwork blocking), but moving a site out of an EPM-using Zone resolves both issues.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to make IE11 work with localhost on windows 8 is by going in the internet options > Security and drop all those bars to the lowest level and disable Protected Mode. 
I'm only using IE11 to see if my developed websites work correctly, not for browsing the internet. For that I have Chrome/Firefox.

Answer (score 4):

I had same issues , I have fixed with the below 3 options

1. Do a DNS Flus using Command Prompt 
    Open a command prompt and type ipconfig /flushdns
2. if 1st option does not work

   clear Ssl cache in IE 11 browser Inter explorer options -> Content -> Clear SSL Settings
3. you can try above 1,2 step still does not works

   go to Internet options -> ADvanced --> click on reset to reset the internet explorer settings
4. Close all Browser windows , open a new session

   it will work I have fixed similer way 
   Hope it helps thank you .