# Page does not let me login using hostname but works fine in localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, iis-8

I have a webpage hosted on a Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.
My webpages login function works fine when I'm using http://localhost/site
however it does not work using http://hostname/site. It sends me to the proper page but during the login function it just keeps posting back to the same page, no error messages unless I use the wrong password or username. This only happens with IE(using version 11).

I tried using Chrome and the page worked fine.

My best bet is something about the internet explorer settings, but I've reset everything, added the page to trusted sites and compability view.

I cannot repeat this phenomenon in my dev environment.

Anyone have any idea? Asp.NET page.

Comment: Have you tried to put this inside web.config? `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` or `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />`

Comment: And what kind of authentication are you using ?

Comment: @KevinMaxwell where in the webconfig would I put that?

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar Forms authentication

Comment: @PeterB `<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>`

Comment: @PeterB inside `<system.webServer>` **>>>** `<httpProtocol>` **>>>** `<customHeaders>`

Comment: Cookie-based forms authentication ? Can you share relevant web.config settings ?

Comment: @KevinMaxwell No change :/

Comment: @PeterB as OndrejSvejdar suggested, please share your web.config forms authentication settings.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" timeout="120" />
    </authentication>

Comment: @PeterB have you tried to put this inside <forms> tag? `name="cookiename" cookieless="UseCookies" slidingExpiration="true"`

Comment: @PeterB please don't forget to clear your IE browser history and then try the above changes.

Comment: @KevinMaxwell I cleared the history and closed the browser between each attempt.

Comment: @PeterB Do you use Classic mode or Integrated mode in IIS Pool?

Comment: I used to have the same issue in one of my applications. The problem was that I had a function to get user's IP address. The function was looping the same DNS Host.

Comment: @KevinMaxwell - I am using the Integrated mode.

Comment: Please try to run your application in 32bit mode and see what happens:
[See more](https://help.webcontrolcenter.com/kb/a1114/how-to-enable-a-32-bit-application-pool-in-iis-7-dedicated-vps.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately no change.

Comment: @PeterB is your app MVC?

Comment: Web application using web forms.

Comment: I'm currently out of option. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800672/ie11-unable-to-connect-to-local-iis-other-browsers-work-fine) will help.

Comment: I would recommend to collect a fiddler trace - to see how auth cookie is handled & share it here.

Comment: Sorry for not following up on this. I got back from my vacation yesterday.
Essentially I just solved the issue. Using fiddler as you guys suggested i investigated the cookies when I stumbled upon this error message: 

"!! WARNING !!: Server hostname contains an underscore and this response sets a cookie. Internet Explorer does not permit cookies to be set on hostnames containing underscores."

This explains why it works on every other browser but not IExplorer 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the hostname contained an underscore and IExplorer doesn't allow cookies to be set by hostnames containing underscores.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316112/prb-session-variables-do-not-persist-between-requests-after-you-instal

Microsoft suggested resolutions:

> To work around this problem, use one of the following methods:
>
> - Rename the domain name and the server name, and use only alphanumeric characters.
> - Browse to the server by using the Internet Protocol (IP) address rather than the domain/server name.